# Loop through dataset and select a range of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data with portfolio numbers in column A. I want to create a macro that loops through column A and stops and selects the data when a new de portfolio number appears.

I have a example below.

```
Portfolio   Owner Name
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000107510  Bravo Top B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
7000108762  Beheermaatschappij J. de Vrind B.V.
```

So the loop selects 7000107510 and stops the loop when is sees a different number (in this case 7000108762). I then want to select the entire rows of data that contains portfolio number 7000107510 and the column next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to find row next to sought value, we can search for it from the bottom using `xlPrevious` direction. It will find last row with that value. Offsetting by one row down, we'll get the row we need.

```
Range("A:A").Find("Portfolio_Number", SearchDIrection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
```

Comment: While this might work, an explanation should really accompany your answer.

Comment: @ItamarG3 Added explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, StartPoint As Long
        Dim strValue As String

        strValue = ""
        StartPoint = 2

        'With statement refer to Sheet1. Change if needed
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            'Find Last row of column A in Sheet1
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'Loop starting from row 2 to LastRow variale. Change Starting position if needed
            For i = 2 To LastRow

                If i >= StartPoint Then

                    strValue = .Range("A" & i).Value

                    For j = i + 1 To LastRow

                        If .Range("A" & j).Value <> strValue Then
                            .Range("A" & j - 1 & ":B" & j - 1).Select
                            Exit For
                        End If

                    Next j

                    StartPoint = j

                End If

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```